# Firefox not completing page load after click sent by selenium on sauce

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

A test which works perfectly well locally with selenium webdriver is timing out when run remotely on saucelabs.com. The same test works for Chrome (both local and on sauce).

From the client code's side, the `click` in the following code is never returning:

```
var someLink = await driver.findElement(By.className('some-class'));
await someLink.click()
```

I'm using `jest` for the test framework with at 60 second timeout, so on the client end, I get that timeout error after a minute.

When I log into sauce and look at the list of commands it processed I see:

```
POST elements
```

With parameters:

```
{"using":"css selector","value":".some-class"}
```

And the returned body is:

```
[{"ELEMENT":"2"}]
```

So that succeeds and finds the link. I then never see a `click` event on that element. Prior click events, and navigation commands are successful.

When I watch the video playback of the session, I see it click the given link and the new page load in Firefox, but the spinner (actually a little dot going back and forth) in the top right never stops.

I can't reproduce with Firefox myself, or even through the manual testing on Saucelabs where you can control the browser and VM through the web.

I'm wondering if there's some synchronous code that's running that just isn't resolving. But I can't figure out how to find that out. The developer tools don't appear to have any way to show currently blocking code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When page is being loaded, Selenium is waiting for `document.readyState` to be `complete`.
Sometimes loading of some resource might stuck - when it tries to get big file and connection is poor, when resource is not reachable because of proxy, when service that provides this resource is down, and so on.

I had the same problem with Firefox and solved it using `eager` page load strategy. 
With this load strategy Selenium will wait for `document.readyState` to be `interactive` - some resources might not be loaded, but main elements of the page are loaded and you can interact with them in common way.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY, "eager");
```

Comment: Thanks! I've since moved on from this project and don't have the opportunity to check if this would fix my issue, but it sounds right.